# Ionic 5 - LargeTitle on top show content above

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm starting from scratch with the standard Ionic 5 Tabs Starter template and the large title block from the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/title#collapsible-large-titles) but above my title block I can the the blured content from below. Is this the correct behavior?

```
const Tab2: React.FC = () => {
return (
<IonPage>
  <IonHeader translucent>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonTitle>Settings</IonTitle>
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>

  <IonContent fullscreen>
    <IonHeader collapse="condense">
      <IonToolbar>
        <IonTitle size="large">Settings</IonTitle>
      </IonToolbar>
      <IonToolbar>
        <IonSearchbar></IonSearchbar>
      </IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
    <ExploreContainer name="Tab 3 page" />
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
);
};
```

[image]

[image]

after scrolling down the second header is correct:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the reason for this issue. It was my fault to duplicate the content. If I add normal cards inside the content section the behavior is correct.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

remove the addition header

```
<IonPage>
  <IonHeader translucent>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonTitle>Settings</IonTitle>
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>

  <IonContent fullscreen>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonSearchbar></IonSearchbar>
    </IonToolbar>
    <ExploreContainer name="Tab 3 page" />
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
```

Comment: the addition header is shown if you scroll down like in the second screenshot. This should normally hidden if the page load.